# Issue when item is updated and using updateItem callback in jsGrid

Tags: jquery, html, jsgrid

I have a simple jsGrid in my HTML page. I configured the grid to enable editing only to the Employee ID column. I also implemented the onItemUpdated callback in my script so that when the Employee ID has been updated, it will trigger the callback and call a web service to retrieve the employee information (e.g., name and address). After the web service respond with result, it will update the item Name and Address, respectively using jsGrid updateItem API.

The problem is after the event triggered, it performs a recursive call to the callback because the updateItem API also re-trigger the onItemUpdated callback again.

```
           onItemUpdated: function (args) {
                console.log(args.item);

                // edit the item.
                $("#jsGrid").jsGrid("updateItem", args.item, {
                    Id: args.item.Id,
                    EmployeeId: args.item.EmployeeId,
                    EmployeeName: "Benjamin",
                    CostCenter: "1234",
                    Department: "ITS Department"
                });
            },
```

Hope you can help me on what is a better strategy to this issue.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

`onItemUpdated` callback is usually used to do some additional handling when an item is updated. For the basic update scenario you just have to define `controller.updateItem` in the config. The updating of the grid will happen automatically.

```
$("#jsGrid").jsGrid({
    ...,

    controller: {
        loadData: function() {
            // retriving data request
            return $.ajax({ ... });
        },

        updateItem: function(item) {
            // updating data request
            return $.ajax({
                url: "http://myresource/api/items"
                type: "PUT",
                data: item
            });
        }
    }

});
```

Comment: I am getting empty row but in database record is updated.

Comment: Does updateItem: function(item){ } works to send the edition of a row and send the data from that row to the database? what does item have? is the entire row of data edited in form of array or something?